# Redis: Sort keys from lists by number of elements

Tags: redis

I have a redis-store that has multiple lists, indexed by `list:name_of_list`. Is it possible to retrieve the keys of all lists sorted in a way that the list with highest number of elements is the first and the list with the lowest number of elements is the last?

Comment: Please elaborate more, what you specifically want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, you will need to get the lengths of the lists, then sort them, then get the elements of each list. You can do that in your client, or if you prefer, you can do that in a Lua function that will act as sort of a stored procedure.

The gist of it, in Python/pseudo code will look like:

```
lists = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3']
lengths = [client.llen(lst) for lst in lists]

# zip and sort the lists and their lengths 
keys_and_lengths = sorted(zip(lists, lengths), key=lamda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)

# Get the members, you can chain them in various ways. You can also use a pipeline
members = [client.lrange(key, 0, -1) for key, _ in keys_and_lengths]
```